# ModelBackend authenticate doesn't receive credentials when using Admin Panel

Tags: python, django

I've setup a custom backend with the following configuration:

Settings.py;

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'users.backends.CustomUserBackend',
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    ),
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('users.backends.CustomUserBackend',)
```

backends.py

```
class CustomUserBackend(ModelBackend):

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):

        if username is None:
            username = request.data.get("username")

        if password is None:
            password = request.data.get("password")

        ....
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

When submitting a request via my API this works as expected and authenticates the user correctly etc. My problem comes when I try and log into the admin panel. The stack trace I'm getting when trying to login is caused by an exception when trying to access `request.data` which is because it's not the correct type to look at, which is correct to how my logic works.

The problem is the authenticate method in here;

```
def authenticate(request=None, **credentials):
    """
    If the given credentials are valid, return a User object.
    """

    for backend, backend_path in _get_backends(return_tuples=True):
        print(backend)
        try:
            inspect.getcallargs(backend.authenticate, request, **credentials)
        except TypeError:
            # This backend doesn't accept these credentials as arguments. Try the next one.
            continue
        try:
            user = backend.authenticate(request, )
        except PermissionDenied:
            # This backend says to stop in our tracks - this user should not be allowed in at all.
            break
        if user is None:
            continue
        # Annotate the user object with the path of the backend.
        user.backend = backend_path
        return user

    # The credentials supplied are invalid to all backends, fire signal
    user_login_failed.send(sender=__name__, credentials=_clean_credentials(credentials), request=request)
```

In here, credentials has the login data `{'username': 'dan', 'password': '12345'}`. If I understand this method correctly (my python is knowledge is limited) it's not finding my authenticate method in my backend with the correct parameters so it's falling back to the default?

Full stack trace from the login error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File ".../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File ".../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File ".../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 407, in login
    return LoginView.as_view(**defaults)(request)
  File ".../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File ".../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File ".../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File ".../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 63, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 141, in post
    if form.is_valid():
  File ".../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 180, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File ".../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 175, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File ".../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 377, in full_clean
    self._clean_form()
  File ".../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 404, in _clean_form
    cleaned_data = self.clean()
  File ".../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 214, in clean
    self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)
  File ".../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 74, in authenticate
    user = backend.authenticate(request, )
  File ".../users/backends.py", line 12, in authenticate
    username = request.data.get("username")
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Comment: A normal WSGIRequest has no attribute `data`. Only `rest_framework`'s own `Request` class has that to abstract over various forms of request data, form-encoded, json, etc. So if you are not in rest_framework context, your code will not work like that. Make it robuster by checking `hasattr(request, 'data')` and using `request.POST` otherwise.

Comment: That fixes, the crash thanks! but it doesn't get around the authenticate method not receiving the username and password from the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I've temporarily fixed this by adding to the authenticate method;

```
def authenticate(request=None, **credentials):
    """
    If the given credentials are valid, return a User object.
    """
    for backend, backend_path in _get_backends(return_tuples=True):

        try:
            inspect.getcallargs(backend.authenticate, request, **credentials)
        except TypeError:
            # This backend doesn't accept these credentials as arguments. Try the next one.
            continue
        try:
            user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)
        except PermissionDenied:
            # This backend says to stop in our tracks - this user should not be allowed in at all.
            break
        if user is None:
            continue
        # Annotate the user object with the path of the backend.
        user.backend = backend_path
        return user

    # The credentials supplied are invalid to all backends, fire signal
    user_login_failed.send(sender=__name__, credentials=_clean_credentials(credentials), request=request)
```

So now the `user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)` method takes the credentials, once logged into the admin panel I can remove this line but would ideally like to know why it's doing it still.